# Special character into querystring .NET

Tags: vb.net, query-string

I need to send the follow querystring:

```
http://prod.intranet.siemens.com.br/drvs/index.aspx?page=2&pag=4&varpatch=%20C:\Documents%20and%20Settings\OPE253\My%20Documents\Ca$@#!
```

Then i try to assing this to a string,but .NET break string at

```
   http://prod.intranet.siemens.com.br/drvs/index.aspx?page=2&pag=4&varpatch=%20C:\Documents%20and%20Settings\OPE253\My%20Documents\Ca$@
```

'#" do not appears in querystring

Any ideas?

Comment: Chris is right below, it's worth noting though this isn't a .Net issue, your browser won't send anything past the `#` or hash, it serves a very specific purpose and it's all client-side.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, because "#" is a reserved character. It's used to link to a specific location in a web page:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_anchor#Overview

So browsers split the URL at the "#".

You'll need to encode the "#" as "%23"

You need to use [`String.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx):

```
Dim outputURL As String = inputURL.Replace("#", "%23")
```

or [`HttpUtility.UrlEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode.aspx) (only encode the querystring):

```
Dim outputQueryString As String = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(inputQueryString)
```